# How to pick elements with certain values in list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples, list-comprehension, combinations

I  want to pick some elements with certain values in list of `tuple`. Assume I have combinatory list of tuples from verticis = [2,3,4,5] which is res = [(2, 3, 5), (2, 4, 5), (3, 4, 5), (2, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4, 5)]

Then I want to pick all the `tuples` that contains `key=[2,4,5]` in the res. I used **List comprehension**

but raised with error: `too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

The output should be : `[(2, 4, 5),(2, 3, 4, 5)]`

```
verticis = [2,3,4,5]
items_to_pick = [2, 4, 5]

i, j = len(items_to_pick), len(verticis)
res1 = [com for sub in range(j) for com in combinations(verticis, sub + 1)] 
res2 = [com for sub in range(i - 1) for com in combinations(verticis, sub + 1)] 

res = list(set(res1) - set(res2)) 

c = [value for idx, value in enumerate(res) if idx in items_to_pick]
c=[value for idx, value in res if idx in items_to_pick]
```

Comment: I changed the question to be more clear.

Comment: I meant to make it more clear. sorry for that I can send it in private if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to extract the `index` and the `value` from each item. In that case, use the `enumerate` function: `c = [value for idx, value in enumerate(res) if idx in items_to_pick]`.

You can find more information at the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Comment: It did not work. There is not all the tuples that contains [2,4,5].

Comment: @Aras in your current function, it looks like you are only extracting tuples in `res` whose index is in `items_to_pick`. If you want to do what you are asking, check out @ShashSinha's answer

Answer (score 1):

```
res= [(2, 3, 5), (2, 4, 5), (3, 4, 5), (2, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4, 5)]

items_to_pick = [2, 4,5] 

selected= [tup for tup in res if all(i in tup for i in items_to_pick)]
```